# play framework jpa testing and transaction handling

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, jpa, playframework-2.2

i'm currently starting a new project using play framework and using hibernate and JPA for the storage part. I have developed my models but i find very inconvenient to test them properly due to the way the JPA plugins handle the transaction. To run my models test now i'm extending this abstract class found on an answer here on stackoverflow (yes i did some research first :) )

```
public abstract class BaseAbstractTest extends TestCase {
EntityManager em;
EntityTransaction transaction;
@Before
public void setUp() {
    FakeApplication app = Helpers.fakeApplication();
    Helpers.start(app);
    Option<JPAPlugin> jpaPlugin = app.getWrappedApplication().plugin(JPAPlugin.class);
    em = jpaPlugin.get().em("default");
    JPA.bindForCurrentThread(em);
    transaction = em.getTransaction();
}


@After
public void tearDown() {
    em.close();
    JPA.bindForCurrentThread(null);
}
```

But to test my utility methods built for the models i still have to begin and commit transaction manually leading to methods like this:

```
public void testRegisterValidate(){
Client client = new Client("name" , "surname" , "mail@email.com" );
transaction.begin();
boolean registered =  (Client.registerUser(client));
transaction.commit();
if (registered)
    System.out.println("Id of client is " + client.id);
else
    System.out.println("Cannot register this user");
}
```

That has some problems, because a persistence exception will be thrown once i commit a transaction, and so, i cannot even catch that in the registerUser Method

My question is:
Does exist a better method to handle this kind of tests? Something like just annotate the model utility methods with @Transactional and let them handle the transactions.
Whare are your experience/advice about handling data and data test in play framework using JPA?
WHERE and HOW should i handle Exception like persistedExceptions or NoResultException keeping in mind that i would like to take the storage part as most separated as possible.
I was even thinking about not using the JPA plugin and build DAO and handle them "the classic way" injecting a SessionFactory object in each DAO and use it to handle data, has anyone of you adopted this solution? What are PROS AND CONS?
Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks